# Not getting all information in web scraping from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, jupyter

I am taking the details of property from a website but it hardly gives the information of 20 property while there are 100. There is no timeout

INPUT:

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get('https://www.century21.com/real-estate/new-york-ny/LCNYNEWYORK/')
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,'html.parser')

all=soup.find_all("div",{'class':'property-card-primary-info'})
#print(soup.prettify())




#len(all)
l=[]
for item in all:
    d={}
    d['price']=item.find('a',{'class':'listing-price'}).text.replace('\n','').replace(' ','')
    add=item.find('div',{'class':'property-address-info'})
    try:
        d['address']=add.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('  ','')
    except:
        d['address']="None"
    try:
        d['beds']=item.find('div',{'class':'property-beds'}).find('strong').text.replace('\n','')
    except:
        d['beds']='None'
    try:
        d['baths']=item.find('div',{'class':'property-baths'}).find('strong').text.replace('\n','')
    except:
        d['baths']='None'
    try:
        d['area']=item.find('div',{'class':'property-sqft'}).find('strong').text
    except:
        d['area']='None'
    l.append(d)

df=pandas.DataFrame(l)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
          price                                            address beds baths   area
0    $1,680,000        161 West 61st Street 3-F New York NY 10023     2     2   None
1    $1,225,000        350 East 82nd Street 2-J New York NY 10028     2     2   None
2    $2,550,000   845 United Nations Plaza 39-E New York NY 10017     2     2   None
3    $1,850,000            57 Reade Street 17-C New York NY 10007     1     1   None
4      $828,000              80 Park Avenue 4-E New York NY 10016     1     1   None
5      $850,000        635 West 42nd Street 19L New York NY 10036     1     1   None
6    $1,749,000        635 West 42nd Street 45D New York NY 10036     2     2   None
7    $1,175,000       340 East 64th Street 11-P New York NY 10065     2     1   None
8    $5,450,000      450 East 83rd Street 24-BC New York NY 10028     5     5   None
9    $4,500,000     524 East 72nd Street 32-CDE New York NY 10021     3     3   None
10   $1,700,000        635 West 42nd Street 42E New York NY 10036     1     1   None
11     $850,000       635 West 42nd Street 15JJ New York NY 10036     1     1   None
12     $800,000       635 West 42nd Street 16JJ New York NY 10036     1     1   None
13  $22,500,000        635 West 42nd Street 28K New York NY 10036     6     6  6,000
14   $1,125,000        635 West 42nd Street 15G New York NY 10036     1     1   None
15   $1,085,000        635 West 42nd Street 14N New York NY 10036     1     1    800
16     $900,000        635 West 42nd Street 18E New York NY 10036     1     1   None
17   $1,600,000        635 West 42nd Street 23K New York NY 10036     2     2  1,070
18   $1,250,000        635 West 42nd Street 24H New York NY 10036     2     1    800
19     $995,000         635 West 42nd Street 4F New York NY 10036     1     1    800
```

But there are 100 property details on website why I am getting only 20. Is there any way so that I can get the all property details.

Answer (score 0):

That page shows only the first 20 items at the beginning. Upon scrolling, the next 20 items are shown. And that is the reason you are getting only the first 20 items.

You could instead scrape from this URL.

```
https://www.century21.com/propsearch-async?lid=CNYNEWYORK&t=0&s=0&r=20&searchKey=244edb9b-0c67-41cc-aa75-1125928b7c87&p=1&o=comingsoon-asc
```

Change the `s` value in multiples of 20.

Example,

```
s=0: The first 20 items will be fetched
s=20: The next 20 items will be fetched
s=40: .....
and so on...
```